# QT получить индекс измененного элемента в QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

Здравствуйте, никак не могу сделать так, чтобы по изменению данных, в какой-нибудь ячейки QTableView срабатывал слот, уже кучу всяких слотов и сигналов перепробовал, работает только сигнал clicked(), когда нажимаешь на данную ячейку. Но мне это не подходит... Вот на этом я сейчас остановился:

```
...

connect(ui->tableView->model(), SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex, QVector<int>)), this, SLOT(changeData(QModelIndex, QModelIndex, QVector<int>)));

...

void StaffsForm::changeData(QModelIndex row, QModelIndex col , QVector<int> vec)
{
    qDebug() << "Заработало!";
}
```

Comment: flags() в модели переопределяли?

Comment: Нет, можно поподробнее?

Comment: Что за модель? Данные в ней точно изменились? Она послала сигнал `dataChanged`?

Comment: Если модель написана вами, то покажите реализацию методов `flags` и  `setData`

Comment: Нет не мной, использовал QStandartItemModel и в нее добавлял Items

Answer (score 0):

У меня так работает:

```
...
connect(model, &QStandardItemModel::itemChanged, this, &ClientData::itemChange);
...

void ClientData::itemChange(QStandardItem *item)
{
    somecode(item->text());
}
```

Comment: Не работает так